# Blocking call in socket.io doesn't seem to block other clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following piece of code:

```
var schedules = io.on('connection', function(client) {
    var schJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'huge_file.json', 'utf8'));
    client.json.send(schJSON);
});
```

`readFileSync` being a blocking call, I figured that while one client's request is being processed by the server, other clients would get queued up. So, if reading the file takes around 10 seconds and I fire off three different connections to the server, the third connection would take around 30 seconds to get a response.

In practice, all three clients get the response almost at the same time (after 10 seconds have elapsed). The three requests were fired from three different machines (with the same external IP address).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the flow to go something like this:

1. First request comes in and does a blocking read of the file.
2. Two more requests come in and their 'connection' callbacks get queued up.
3. The initial file read completes and the async `client.json.send` call starts sending the response.
4. The two other requests' callbacks get called, with each one's `readFileSync` call completing very quickly since the file is in the disk cache and then `client.json.send` is called so that all three requests' responses are being sent in parallel.
5. All three requests complete, potentially close to the same time because step 4 is so quick.

Comment: Any idea how long the disk's cache is maintained? Because if I refresh the first client after getting a response, it once again takes 10 seconds to get a response. The server is a free instance of AppFog (https://www.appfog.com/), if that helps.

Comment: @Amey Then it's probably the download of the response to the client that's taking the bulk of the 10 seconds.

Comment: Sadly, that's probably not the case. The returned json contains just one string of around 30 bytes.

Comment: @Amey I thought you said it was a huge file?  Anyway, add some logging to your code to figure out where the time is being spent as you can only get so far just thinking about it.

Comment: Yep, will do that next. It's a friend's production code so I can't play with it till next week, thought I might find out something obvious here that I'd missed.